# How to dynamically create table in html with certain constraints?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamically-generated

i want to take input from user(number) and display image as many times as number.If user inputs 5 then the image should be displayed 5 times next to each other with corresponding number below the images-Below 1st image '1' 2nd Image '2'.Basically putting this table in loop.

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>


<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>
<IMG SRC="C:/Users/User/Desktop/RE/G.JPG">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN="CENTER">1</TD>
</TABLE>"


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: where does your "input" comes from ? is it an <input> where user enter the value ? is it set on page load ? if page load, why do you want to use JS, you don't have php ?

Comment: So write a loop that adds `<tr>` and `<td>` elements to the table as many times as needed. What's the problem?

Comment: I did that @Barmar but images are coming one below the other.

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, you have to post it. It sounds like you put each `<td>` in a different row, instead of in the same row.

Comment: @PierreGranger ya input tag .<p>Click the button to.</p>
<input 
type="number" id="myNumber" value=""><button onclick="imag()">Try 

it</button>

Answer (score 1):

You can add an input and a button to trigger the function.
You could also check if the inserted value is actually a number or not.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var times = parseInt($('#times').val());
  for (i=1;i<=times;i++) {
    $('#table-wrp').append('<table class="table-times"><tbody><tr><td><img src="http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/icon.png" /></td></tr><tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');
  }
});

$(document).on('input', '#times', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var value = that.val(); 
  if ((value != '' || value != false) && !isNaN(value)) {
    $('#add').prop('disabled', false);         
  } else {
    $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
  }      
});
```

```css
#table-wrp {
  height: 80px;
}

.table-times {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-times td { 
   border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; 
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="times" />
<button id="add" disabled>Add</button>
<div id="table-wrp"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **jQuery** for this task and write a function that generates HTML with a dynamic value:

**Complete Solution**

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generateTable(number) {
            return "<table><tr><td>" + 
                   "<img src='C:/Users/User/Desktop/RE/G.JPG'></td></tr><tr><td align='center'>" +
                   number +
                   "</td></table>";
        }

        $(function(){
            var userInput = 3;

            for (var i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
                $('#dynamic').append(generateTable(i + 1)); 
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='dynamic'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function() {
  var tab = "<div></div>";
  var num = prompt("Enter a number");
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $("#tab").append("<div class='left'><div><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150'></div><div>" + (i + 1) + "</div></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
div.left {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tab">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or for a pure javascript version of Pugazh's answer

```js
var tab = "<div></div>";
var num = prompt("Enter a number");
for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    document.getElementById('tab').innerHTML += "<div><div><img src='http://placehold.it/150x150'></div><div></div></div>";
}
```

```css
img{
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab"></div>
```

This will work just as well, but doesn't require jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<div id="tbl"></div>

</BODY>
</HTML>

<script>

var num = prompt("Enter a number");
var div=document.getElementById("tbl");
var l1='',l2="";
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
  l1 += '<td><img src="C:/Users/User/Desktop/RE/G.JPG"></td>';
  l2 += '<td>'+i+'</td>';
}  
div.innerHTML = "<table><tr>"+l1+"</tr><tr>" + l2 + "</tr></table>";

</script>
```

Comment: images are coming one below the other! Any way to get it inline